# Getting SocketTimeOutException while accessing webservice with Large data in C# .net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm a php programmer and i know nothing about C# .net!  and now i have to codeing in C# for once in .net mvc4 for access to a web service with soap. i can get any functionality with help of GOD and of course stackoverflow except one with a large data  . 
in php i have this issue too ,  but i handle it with this code
  ini_set("memory_limit","50M");
  ini_set("max_execution_time",-1);

i dont know how increase memory_limit and max_execution_time in C# and i can't found a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set those properties in the appropriate Binding node in the web.config. Here is a quick example node I stole from another website. It shows a lot of the properties, but please make changes intelligently. Any property currently in your config not in the example below should be retained, for instance. Hope this helps.

```
<binding name="[Your Service Binding Name]" 
         closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
         openTimeout="00:01:00" 
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
         maxBufferSize="65536" 
         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" />
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help!